# correct usage of "will have"

Tags: tense

In this website: [British Council Learn English](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-have-and-would-have), they say—"We use ***will have*** when we are looking back from a point in time in the future, ***or looking back from the present"*::**

> It's half past five. Dad **will have** finished work by now.

but in other website I could(?) only find examples where "*will have*" is used in future

> Next month my parents **will have** been together for thirty years.

Can "***will have***" be used in present Or "***should have***" should be used instead ?

> It's half past five. Dad **should have** finished work by now.

Comment: Yes, _Dad will have finished work by now_ is perfectly fine. The speaker has not seen their father leave his workplace, but knows that it is past his normal finishing time. _Should have_ suggests less certainty (maybe he quite often works late).

Comment: Is it common ?I dont see "will have" too much.may be its not used much

Comment: It's quite usual in this particular context (calculating that something has very probably happened by now).